# Having problems with fluent api and relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having trouble with entity framework 4.1 and relationships.

Here are my classes:

```
[Table("PROJTABLE")]
    public class Certifikat {
        [Key]
        public long Recid { get; set; }

        public String Projid { get; set; }           
        public virtual StandardAndScope StandardInfo { get; set; }
}

[Table("DS_CRT_PROJSTANDARDSCOPE")]
    public class StandardAndScope {
        //[Key]
        //public long RECID { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public String Projid { get; set; }

        public String Standard { get; set; }
        public String Scope { get; set; }
    }
```

Since I have no control over the databases, I can't change the keys and id's to support the conventions, and I'm stuck with this setup.

My problem is, Certifikat CAN have a relationship with one StandardAndScope. The key in both tables are called Projid - but this isn't strictly the primary key in the database for either tables.

All I really want is to say: "certifikat c join standardandscope s on c.Projid=s.Projid"

How do I accomplish this with fluent api?

Comment: Do both entities reference a `Project` entity?

Comment: Dynde. My question is pretty relevant. If they reference the same Project entity you can use these navigation properties.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice your comment. There is actually no project entity (if I had the opportunity I would kill the guy who made this database). However I found out, there's only a one-to-many relationship IF a different column has a certain value ("crt"), but I don't know if I can tell entity framework to ONLY map rows where this value is set

Comment: OK, bad design, sigh. You can't solve it with mapping because then `Projid` should be the identifier of one of the entities. You'll have to resort to ad hoc joining as the answer shows. (I pray you won't find the data base designer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
var result = dataContext.Certifikats
    .Join(dataContext.StandardAndScopes,
        c => c.Projid,
        s => s.Projid,
        (c, s) => new
        {
            Certifikat = c,
            StandardAndScope = s
        });
```

Where `dataContext` is an instance of your `DbContext` class.

Comment: Well, this wouldn't exactly be utilizing the strength of EF's navigational properties. I shouldn't have to rely on joining data at the moment I need it.

Comment: @Dynde, I don't see any navigational properties defined in your classes.

Comment: Really? I thought the virtual StandardAndScope StandardInfo was a navigational property. I will, however, have to resort to this joining of classes instead of using navigational properties.

Comment: How would I do this join when there's a one-to-many relationship with standardscope? Some sort of List<StandardAndScope> = s - but s is singular?

Comment: @Dynde, I did not understand your question.

Comment: A certifikat can have multiple standardandscopes, but with this anonoymous type, there is a single certifikat and standardandscope.
However, it doesn't matter, I chose a different route. I made an extension method on the certifikat to get a list of standardandscopes directly from the dbcontext.